# Unable to load python entry_point when developing python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, entry-point

I am trying to develop a python package that is importable and also has entry_point to call from shell.

When trying to call the entry point I get:

`pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pysec-aws 0.1.dev1 (/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/pysec-aws), Requirement.parse('pysec-aws==0.1.dev0'))`

Essentially what I did before getting this error, is incrementing the version from `0.1.dev0` to `0.1.dev1` in setup.py, and running `python setup.py sdist` and then `pip install -e .`

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to install development versions of packages you are actively developing and bundling with setuptools?

Comment: do you get this error when launching code from `pysec-aws` package itself or another package depending on it? Also, the complete error trace along with the `setup.py` skeleton would be nice.

Comment: My guess is that you have some other package that declares an entry point to `pysec-aws` and declares dependency on `pysec-aws` of exact version `0.1.dev0`. Now you bumped `pysec-aws` to `0.1.dev1` so the other package has no valid dependency anymore, and this is what is checked when `pkg_resources` loads the entry points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that fixed this issue was to create a new virtualenv.

Apparently my `virtualenv/bin` had compiled (`.pyc`) and non-compiled (`.py`) references to the old version for some reason - they were probably not upgraded / removed when I installed the new version.

Once I created a new virtualenv and re-installed required packages I was able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ah, I am happy to hear you resolved the problem.  In your case you mentioned both source and compiled source.  For what it is worth, I had a case once where leftover `.pyc` alone (not venv related) caused a problem.  I have forgotten the details but I think I found that problem by having some incongruous grep results.

Answer (score 1):

The error is complaining that the application version does not match the version declared in setup.py.  Try checking the `__version__` set in your application.

You might consider using a single source for the version to avoid this problem.  There are a number of different options outlined at https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/. One simple technique, if there are not any external dependencies, is

```
import myapp
setup(
    ...
    version=myapp.__version__
    ...
)
```

Comment: I don't have a manifest file, and I do have package dependencies.
Where should `__version__` be defined?

Comment: I added `__version__='0.1dev1'` to my `__init__.py` file and used the first technique in the link you provided.
The package builds and is installed fine as before, but when I try to invoke entry_point from shell, I get the same error

Comment: @EytanAvisror by manifest I meant the setup.py declared version.  I will fix 
 that.  As for the error, do you still have a reference to 0.1.dev0 somewhere in your project?  (Note it looks like you lost a period in your comment's referenced version)

Comment: No references for dev0 anywhere.. by the way, when I change `__version__ ` back to `0.1.dev0` and install it it works.

Comment: I am not sure, sorry.  The only other thing that comes to mind is something like this https://packaging.python.org/guides/multi-version-installs/ if you had a previous install leftover but I don't know if it would cause this error or not.